Angular app won't load when trying to connect to a socket but no error
I'm trying to get a socket connection between Angular and Python. This is my first time trying to do this so I may be making a really obvious mistake.
All the code is below, for now I am just trying to get it to connect, make the handshake then be able to send a message from angular and see it printed in the Python console. I have run the Python and opened Postman and I can see messages sent from Postman in Python so the Python server is working.
Whenever I try to run the Angular app the page loads for ever and in the network activity, all I can see is a pending localhost document, however if I remove the BoardSessionSocketService from the constructor, it loads fine. Is it waiting for a response from the Python? How can I fix this?
app.module.ts (with unrelated stuff removed)
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { BoardSessionSocketService } from './services/board-session-socket.service';

const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:8988', options: {} };


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)],
  providers: [
    BoardSessionSocketService,
    provideClientHydration()
   ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

websocket service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';

@Injectable()
export class BoardSessionSocketService {
  constructor(private socket: Socket) {
    socket.connect()
  }

  sendMessage(msg: string) {
    this.socket.emit('message', msg);
  }
  
}

the component I'm trying to connect the web socket from
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Note } from '../board.component';
import { BoardSessionSocketService } from '../../services/board-session-socket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-column',
  templateUrl: './column.component.html',
  styleUrl: './column.component.less'
})

export class ColumnComponent {

  @Input() columnTitle:string = ""
  @Input() notes:Note[] = []

  constructor(private boardSocket: BoardSessionSocketService) {
    this.boardSocket.sendMessage("Hello, this is angular")
  }

}

My Python server
import asyncio
import websockets

CONNECTIONS = set()


async def echo(websocket):
    if websocket not in CONNECTIONS:
        CONNECTIONS.add(websocket)
    async for message in websocket:
        print(message)
        websockets.broadcast(CONNECTIONS, message)


async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", 8988):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever
asyncio.run(main())

I have tried messaging the server with postmate and can see it working fine, I have tried running the angular app with the service commented out and it runs fine, so I believe the error is somewhere in the service, like it's expecting a response and not getting one.

yes, it is waiting for connection as you are trying to connect in constructor of the service and blocking rest of the application to load. This is not good practice. You should try to get connection in asynchronous way.

That's what I thought originally, but when I put a console.log message below that connect method, the log message was printed in the angular terminal. And even after I remove that method call it still loads forever.

In my case, Disabling the SSR server-side rendering resolved it.
Inside the angular.json under development add/update ssr and prerender to false

ttps://i.sstatic.net/fuyhmA6t.png
